# "Order up!", "We're going to need a bigger cup!"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I was watching an SNL clip, [Meet Cute](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgfiXtvej7Q) and I couldn't understand their first dialogue.

Two people ordered the same soy coffee with latte milk.

> Guy: That's crazy. Nobody ever gets my order.
>   Girl: Order up!
>   Guy: We're going to need a bigger cup!

1. "Nobody ever gets my order." Does this mean that no one orders the "Soy coffee with latte milk" like him or no one has ever grabbed the coffee mistakenly, which he ordered?
2. What's the meaning of "Order up!" and "We're going to need a bigger cup!"?

I'm trying to understand this scene but I don't get it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I agree with your first interpretation. No one ever orders the same item that he orders.
2. Sometimes at restaurants and diners, someone (I think it's the chef) says "Order up!" when the food is ready. So she's saying "order up!" because their coffee is ready. She's trying to be cute and funny.
   Often, when movie lines or book quotes become famous, people parody them, or adapt them, to their particular situation as a joke. Here, I believe "we're going to need a bigger cup" is supposed to be a funny variation of the famous line from the movie *Jaws*

   > [You're Gonna Need a Bigger Boat](https://youtu.be/2I91DJZKRxs?t=33)